# Parse.com updating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform, session-cookies

I have created a user in _User class of parse.com.  My application is built using ruby on rails with parse gem (https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client).

I am having a hard time updating a user in the _User class because parse requires some sort of authentication.

This is how I try to update a user:
After logging in, I save the session token. Then in my controller, when I try to save an update to a user, I set the header before the user.save

Code snippet:

```
def add_user 

user = Parse::Query.new("_User").eq("objectId", session[:user_id]).get.first
request.headers["X-Parse-Session-Token"] = session[:session_token]

user.array_add_unique("athlete_id", "john")
user.save

end
```

My issue is sometimes the application would correctly update a user, but other times it would respond with a 206: Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError. If I hit back and retry, it works again. Maybe it has something to do with cookies?

Comment: tip for stackoverflow: select your code and use `ctrl+k` to fromat the text into code

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around.. kind of clunky.

Instead of using parse and updating directly, I just used the net http library and api requests for parse and made a put request.